# Activity gets killed when orientation is changed

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities in my project- Splash and AActivity. Splash is the main activity and is working fine. But if i change the orientation while Splash activity is running, the UI of splash activity goes off but it opens the AActivity after 10 sec.

code for splash activity is -

```
public class Splash extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try{
                    sleep(10000);   

                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent AActivityIntent = new Intent("com.example.ex.AACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(AActivityIntent);
                }
            }};

        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();                                   
    }

}
```

I want to retain the UI of splash activity for 10 seconds even if orientation is changed. After 10 sec splash activity should be finished. How to do it ???

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you doing the following:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
    private Thread timer;
    private volatile long timeLeft;
    private long timeStarted;
    private long timeStopped;

    private static final long TIME_TO_SHOW = 100000
    private static final String KEY_TIME_LEFT = "timeLeftToRun";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            timeLeft = savedInstanceState.getLong(KEY_TIME_LEFT, 0);
        } else {
            timeleft = TIME_TO_SHOW;
        }

        timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(timeLeft);   
                    Intent AActivityIntent = new Intent("com.example.ex.LISTSCREEN");
                    startActivity(AActivityIntent);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }};
        timeStarted = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        timer.interrupt();
        timeStopped = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        finish();                                   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        timeLeft -= timeStopped - timeStarted;
        if (timeLeft > 0) outState.putLong(timeLeft);
    }
}
```

The main idea here is that you kill the thread if the activity is killed, but you take a note for how long it has run and how much time it has left. When the activity is restored, you do the same actions, except you have to wait for a smaller amount of time.

The code above is, of course, untested, but it should illustrate the idea.

Comment: ++ for not going for the lazy approach.

Comment: @Malcolm Thanks Malcolm. I have tried your method, removed some syntax errors from your code but am getting error "app stopped unexpectedly..." while running the app on my device. Don't know why ?

Comment: You should look up the logs in [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html), they should have the exception and the stack trace.

Comment: @Malcolm Now its working but when i change orientation, the UI goes off. BTW someone suggested about using asynctasks, can help me with this ??

Comment: @sam UI goes away because you finish your activity in `onPause()`. You should move call to `finish()` to the end of the `run()` implementation. As I said, I didn't test my code, so it may need some polishing. AsyncTasks definitely won't help you, they will only complicate things.

Comment: @Malcolm tries this but no luck. Actually the problem is the thread gets re-executed when orientation is changed hence the AACTIVITY is created twice and thrice (i.e. the no of times orientations is changed).

Comment: The thread is supposed to be interrupted if the activity gets paused, and then it should catch InterruptedException and just die. So it seems strange that it runs after the activity has been recreated.

Answer (score 2):

Insert into your manifest these below block. 
It means orientation change situation controlled by your "activity".
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

> android:configChanges="orientation"

And more.

Override "onConfigurationChanged" method.

Try this. You can do everything you want.

Comment: And you will need to remember to change the layouts yourself if it depends on the screen orientation.

Comment: This is probably the simplest solution that will work, as long as you don't need your splash screen to rotate.

Comment: @Brigham That I agree, my solution is more "Android" way of doing this, but it is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Thread for delayed launch of activity use [Alarmmanager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), even if you are quitting the app you could always cancel the pending Alarm